# Java ternary operators and same-variable assignment

Tags: java, syntax-error, ternary-operator

I was creating a class to use as a backbone for creating an item with durability in games (much like a pick or sword in Minecraft) and ran across an error while creating a method which contained a ternary operator:

```
public void setMaxDurability(int newMax) {
    newMax > MAX_DURABILITY ? maxDurability = MAX_DURABILITY : maxDurability = newMax;
}
```

This code throws an error at the ">" operator in Eclipse, saying "Syntax error on token ">", -> expected." For clarificiation, newMax is the new maximum durabilty to set the variable maxDurability to, but it cannot be greater than the constant MAX_DURABILITY. All types are int (and the constant is final), so I don't understand what the problem is.

I managed to get the method to work using

```
public int setMaxDurability(int newMax) {
    return maxDurability = (newMax > MAX_DURABILITY ? MAX_DURABILITY : newMax);
}
```

but I was wondering why the first code block didn't work. Any help?

Comment: Order of operations.  `?` and `:` come before `=`.  So what you were trying was effectively `(newMax > MAX_DURABILITY ? maxDurability) = (MAX_DURABILITY : maxDurability) = newMax;` which doesn't make too much sense at all.

Comment: Incidentally, you didn't need to change the return type to `int`.  You can leave it as `void` and drop the `return`.

Comment: Ooooh, ok. I know I didn't have to change return types, that was just something I forgot to switch back after attempting to debug. So I assume then that you must always make the assignment outside of the ternary operator?

Comment: Well, no.  It's actually legal to write `newMax > MAX_DURABILITY ? ( maxDurability = MAX_DURABILITY ) : (maxDurability = newMax);` but there's not much point.

Answer (score 0):

Should be :

```
public void setMaxDurability(int newMax) {
    maxDurability = newMax > MAX_DURABILITY ? MAX_DURABILITY : newMax;
}
```